# What are options for a global incrementing counter?

Tags: azure, architecture, distributed-system

I am building a system that would benefit from a global incrementing counter. Basically, a service that increments a counter and returns the value. I've tried Azure Page Blobs (counter increment header), Redis (INCR) and SQL Server (Identity). They all work, but the first two are fairly slow, generally taking on the order of a second to generate 2000-3000 numbers. SQL Server is much faster, but only after the connection is open.

What are other options, either in Azure, AWS, or software (e.g., redis)? Are there any services that are especially good at this?

Comment: **Must** it be strictly and densely increasing? Because this will always be a bottleneck. We have workers reserve chunks of integers and then vend those locally. This means every integer is only used once, and the counter is not a bottleneck, but they aren't necessarily in order, nor will every integer be used if a host crashes. This is usually acceptable.

Comment: In general yes, otherwise blocks could be reserved. The core issue is that we're sending messages to Event Hub (or Kafka) and order is only maintained within a partition, and having a global order would be very helpful.

Comment: @ErickT Were you able to device a scalable solution? I was thinking to use Redis INCR but looking at the numbers you found about it's performance,  bit skeptical about using it now.

Comment: I ended up using SQL server - it was orders of magnitude faster than everything else. It was in a stand alone table with no other columns and no indexes. It was able to do thousands per second across a dozen VMs hitting a single database.

I think Postgres or MySQL would likely work as well.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [AWS DynamoDB Atomic Counters](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithItems.html#WorkingWithItems.AtomicCounters) to implement the Global Counter.

> You can use the UpdateItem operation to implement an atomic counter—a
>   numeric attribute that is incremented, unconditionally, without
>   interfering with other write requests. (All write requests are applied
>   in the order in which they were received.) With an atomic counter, the
>   updates are not idempotent. In other words, the numeric value will
>   increment each time you call UpdateItem.

This allows to build a reliable counter where you can adjust the throughput depending on your scale (Autoscaling enabled) and also to replicate across the Globe with recently introduced [Global Tables](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/global-tables/)(Optionally) which provides fast, local, read and write performance.

> Global Tables builds upon DynamoDB’s global footprint to provide you
>   with a fully managed, multi-region, and multi-master database that
>   provides fast, local, read and write performance for massively scaled,
>   global applications. Global Tables replicates your Amazon DynamoDB
>   tables automatically across your choice of AWS regions.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I ran it through some tests, and it was about half the performance of the Azure blob property update and 1/6 of the redis performance (in terms of time to get 1000 numbers on 10 threads). It was about half as fast as Azure blob property in terms in latency to get a single number.